# iptables: how to drop packets by their first bytes

Tags: bash, ubuntu, iptables

I want all packets whose content starts with `"\x18\x00"` to be dropped.
And so, I wrote the following config:

```
iptables -N LIMIT
iptables -I INPUT -j LIMIT
iptables -A LIMIT -p udp -m string --string "\x18\x00" --algo kmp -j DROP
```

But iptables turns my bytes into a string and no packets are dropped.

Answer (score 1):

I add "$" before my bytes string,like this:

```
iptables -N LIMIT
iptables -I INPUT -j LIMIT
iptables -A LIMIT -p udp -m string --string $"\x18\x00" --algo kmp -j DROP
```